# How to resize the form below because it is huge

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fix-cm} %{\fontsize{80}{0}\selectfont LaTeX}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

% one third of the Moebius Strip
%: \strip{<angle>}
\newcommand{\strip}[1]{%
\shadedraw[very thick,shading=color wheel,rotate=#1]
 (0:2.8453) ++ (-30:1.5359) arc (60:0:2)
 -- ++  (90:5) arc (0:60:2) -- ++ (150:3) arc (60:120:2) 
 -- ++ (210:5) arc (120:60:2) -- cycle;}

%: \MoebiusStrip{<text1>}{<text2>}{<text3>}
\newcommand{\MoebiusStrip}[3]{%
\begin{scope} [transform shape]
    \strip{0}
    \strip{120}
    \strip{-120}
    \draw (-60:3.5) node[scale=6,rotate=30] {#1};
    \draw (180:3.5) node[scale=4,rotate=-90]{#3};
    % redraw the first strip after clipping
    \clip (-1.4,2.4)--(-.3,6.1)--(1.3,6.1)--(5.3,3.7)--(5.3,-2.7)--cycle;
    \strip{0}
    \draw (60:3.5) node [gray,xscale=-4,yscale=4,rotate=30]{#2};
\end{scope}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [rotate=22]
  \MoebiusStrip{Ti{\color{orange}\textit{k}}Z}{for}{\LaTeX}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like this? `[rotate=22,scale=.5]`

Comment: ... and you no not need `\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}` here either ...